How can I see which file is being processed when rebuilding org-agenda?
I'm trying to debug why rebuilding my org-agenda is taking so long.
Can I print to the Echo Area which file is being processed, so as to be verbose?

Of course: add a (message file) to the top of the file loop in org-agenda-list. That looks like this: (while (setq file (pop files)) ...) and it's on line 4486 of org-agenda.el in my version of Org mode (release_9.7.15-163-g3ff21c). Make it look like this: (while (setq file (pop files)) (message file)...). The file names will be overwritten fairly quickly in the echo area, but if one takes a long time, it will stick around for a while.

I have been out of the loop for several years, but the last time I played with org-mode, the org agenda files (main flat text files) are all searched for each day within a range of dates; e.g., the 1st of the month, search every agenda file; the second of the month, search every agenda file; and so forth..  To speed up the search, reduce the time span.

@NickD Great, that worked perfectly. Thanks. I can't mark a comment as an answer, though;)

Made the comment into an answer...

@lawlist: that is still the case, so your comment is still very relevant - yearly agendas are a pain... The other thing is to archive DONE items, reducing the time to traverse a file and reducing the number of files to a minimum (but don't worry about 10 files or  50 files - start worrying at 100 or more, always depending on the horsepower of your CPU) - generally speaking, the files are only opened once ( the buffers are kept around, so you are trading off memory against speed), but still, opening a couple of hundred (or a couple of thousand) files at once might produce a noticeable pause...

Of course: add a (message file) to the top of the file loop in org-agenda-list. That looks like this: (while (setq file (pop files)) ...) and it's on line 4486 of org-agenda.el in my version of Org mode (release_9.7.15-163-g3ff21c). Make it look like this: (while (setq file (pop files)) (message file)...). The file names will be overwritten fairly quickly in the echo area, but if one takes a long time, it will stick around for a while.
